# getenv('SYMFONY_ENV') is empty in app/console from composer install, but OK elsewhere

Tags: symfony, environment-variables, composer-php

To deploy my Symfony app on production I run the following command in a bash script:

```
php composer.phar install --no-dev --optimize-autoloader
```

And I got the following error :

> Script
>   Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache
>   handling the post-install-cmd event terminated with an exception
>
> An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'" command.

This is because getenv('SYMFONY_ENV') in the app/console returns an empty value, while executing the commands from composer.json post-install-cmd. Therefore the $env value is not set to **prod** but to **dev** (default one).

However, the SYMFONY_ENV value is ok.

In the terminal, if I run:

```
printenv SYMFONY_ENV
```

It prints **prod**

If I run:

```
php -r "print_r(getenv('SYMFONY_ENV'));"
```

It prints **prod**

What I am missing or doing wrong ?

Comment: does it work if you type export SYMFONY_ENV=prod just before composer install?

Comment: unfortunately no, it does the same problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just realized that I was running

`sudo php composer.phar install --no-dev --optimize-autoloader`

instead of

`php composer.phar install --no-dev --optimize-autoloader`

In my case (ubuntu 14.04), I had defined SYMFONY_ENV in /etc/environment and I thought it was accessible for all users, but it's not the case for sudo. I solved my problem running my command without sudo (because it had no reasons to be).

Another solution could be to run `sudo -E php ...` to preserve the user environment as suggested here : https://askubuntu.com/questions/161924/how-do-i-set-persistent-environment-variables-for-root